# How can I write use python libraries with ironpython in .NET?

Tags: python, c#, .net, ironpython

I am writing a few lines of python code within my .NET app using IronPython, to work with CSV files. I am using pythons CSV library for this purpose but it's not working. The library is not being imported withing IronPython.

Here is the sample of my python code:

```
import csv

with open("infile.dat") as infile, open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    prev = ''
    csv_writer.writerow(['ID', 'PARENT_ID'])
    for line in infile.read().splitlines():
        csv_writer.writerow([line, prev])
        prev = line
```

Here is my c# code:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DatFileReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var py = Python.CreateEngine();
            try
            {
                py.ExecuteFile("D://myPy.py");
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your IronPython standard library path to your engine to get it working.

So this should work if you installed IronPython manually on your computer:

```
ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add("C:\\Path\\To\\IronPython\\StandardLib");
py.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
```

So if you fix the path to the Standard Lib it should work.

The following link should help you to import and use the IronPython standard library over the NuGet package manager:

https://www.needfulsoftware.com/IronPython/IronPythonCS2